# WordPress plugins and themes incompatible with CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, plugin

I am looking for a way to find which plugins incompatible with CiviCRM without deactivating them and install one by one. 
And if you have any experience with your WordPress website please share here. 
I fond this (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/incompatibilities/) link but I am looking a way to know which my plugins incompatible with CiviCRM.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the wiki page [WordPress plugins and themes incompatible with CiviCRM](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=120029201).

Comment: Thank Jon. I am looking for a way to test which one of Wordpress plugins don't work with CiviCRM. Especially new plugins or new versions